# Raspberry Pi 4 Touchscreen Not turning on

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, poe

So, I recently decided to upgrade an old project from a Raspberry Pi 3 to a 4. This Raspberry Pi is powered over Ethernet and needs a touchscreen attached to it. After I connected the `PoE` hat and the screen together as I did the last time, I tried powering it on to make sure that everything was working as intended. The Raspberry Pi would receive power through the `PoE`, but the monitor wouldn't. Even if I plugged in the monitor directly, the display still wouldn't work. I have verified that the image on the MicroSD works, and would display if I used the micro HDMI input, but is not working with the monitor connected to it. I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with it.

[image: Raspberry Pi w/ Everything connected]

[image: How the Monitor is connected to the Pi]

Comment: You've got the power (5V) and GND from the screen connected to completely the wrong pins on your RPi   https://pinout.xyz/pinout/5v_power

Comment: Yeah, I can't connect them to the normal 5V and GND Pins because they are covered up by the PoE Hat.

Comment: There only are two 5V pins and your display won't run on 3.3V. Time to re-examine your project and see if 5V is directly available on the PoE HAT.